# Does Wordpress check for updates of a plugin via plugins root folder name?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, version-control

I just completed writing a plugin from another plugin. When I changed the developer name, version and other details from the plugin file, I thought the version tracing would now be done using the new name of the plugin but it actually linked the update to the older plugin until I changed the root folder name for the plugin. Wasn't the update supposed to be happen from the details provided in the file? Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses the 'plug-in slug' to identify a plug-in (and uses this as an 'id' for plug-in updates, though its not clear how, as the code isn't published). The plug-in slug is determined by the location of the `.php` file header containing the comment header necessary for plug-ins. (see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L234))

So if your main plug-in file is `...wp-content/plugins/pluginA/pluginA.php` your plug-in slug is `pluginA/pluginA.php`, and will by default check for plug-in updates using that slug.

So to give your plug-in a different slug its necessary to change the name of the plug-in file/directory.

Of course its also possible to just prevent your plug-in from checking for updates or change where it looks (e.g. [Have WP Theme update from Git Repository](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101754/have-wp-theme-update-from-git-repository/101759#101759)). (This is not allowed for repository-hosted plug-ins).